# matlab - function strel input type error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

When I try `se = strel('square', 2.4);`, this error occurs:

```
??? Error using ==> iptcheckinput
Function STREL expected its second input, SIZE, to be integer-valued.

Error in ==> strel>ParseInputs at 1154
        iptcheckinput(M, {'double'}, {'scalar' 'integer' 'real' 'nonnegative'}, ...

Error in ==> strel>strel.strel at 146
                [type,params] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});
```

So, I changed the input value `2.4` to `int8(2.4)`, then another error occurs:

```
??? Error using ==> iptcheckinput
Function STREL expected its second input, SIZE,
to be one of these types:

  double

Instead its type was int8.

Error in ==> strel>ParseInputs at 1154
        iptcheckinput(M, {'double'}, {'scalar' 'integer' 'real' 'nonnegative'}, ...

Error in ==> strel>strel.strel at 146
                [type,params] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});
```

I think `2.4` is double type and `int8(2.4)` is integer, doesn't it?

So I can't understand those errors.

I want `strel('square', 2.4)` to be `strel('square', 2)`.

What should I do? What does that error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to change `2.4` to `2` you can use `fix` function. For example:

```
fix(2.4) == 2 // true
```

So, write the code likes the following:

```
 strel('square', fix(2.4))
```

Comment: what is the difference between `fix` and `int8`?

Comment: the result of the fix is usually `int32`.

Comment: Then, `int32(2.4)` is the same as `fix(2.4)`?
If so, why do you recommend `fix()` to me, instead of `int32()`?

Comment: As I said usually. it depends on your machine. So,the point is `fix` return an integer in general terms of the machine, but `int32` returns exactly an integer with 32 bits. Therefore, it would be better to use `fix`, although it might there is no difference between `int32` and `fix` on your machine.

Comment: `int8` and `int32` round to the nearest integer. `fix` gives the next integer closer to zero. So `int8(2.7) = 3` and `int8(-2.7) = -3`, but `fix(2.7) = 2` and `fix(-2.7) = -2`.